# Переименовать [osx] в [macos]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, переименование-метки

Apple переименовала операционную систему для своих компьютеров из OS X в macOS ещё в 2016 году вместе с выпуском macOS Sierra. Думаю, стоит отразить это изменение в метке, поскольку новое название уже используется в новой документации, на сайте Apple и во многих сторонних ресурсах для разработчиков под macOS.

Сейчас метка [osx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) имеет [macos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) в качестве синонима. Предлагаю переименовать саму метку в [macos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos), а [osx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) сделать синонимом.

Comment: Как по мне – [macos] не очень выглядит, лучше уж переименовать в [mac-os], или сделать основной существующую [mac-os-x] (это будет уместно? специалисты, выскажитесь)

Comment: Голосовалку запилите. Я лично за [macos] или просто [mac].

Comment: Думаю, можно отмечать ответ как принятый. Лучше бы, правда, чтоб PP отметился в ответах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, что в 2018 сделали основной [osx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx), учитывая, что с 2016 система имеет название [macos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos). Вроде как наоборот надо было сделать.

**UPD:** теперь основная [macos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos).

Comment: Так синонимизация вроде как с 15 года.

Comment: @alexolut значит я лопухнулся. Смотрел на дату вопроса. Удаление моих ответов выбило из колеи. Мысли путаются. Надеюсь, сердечко выдержит. А то такой стресс, такой стресс.

Comment: баллотируйся, а то проиграешь!

Comment: @alexolut в президенты? Ибо на моём веку я вряд ли новые выборы на ruSO увижу)

Comment: @alexolut а по поводу метки. Вот в данном случае стоит её менять после смены названия или нет?

Comment: мне кажется, что метка должна отражать текущую ситуацию, иначе нужно разрывать синонимы и держать пару меток, как питон-2-3, например.

Comment: @alexolut т.е. нужно основной [tag:macos] сделать? Надо на MSE поискать обсуждения.

Comment: угу. Я думаю, направление синонимизации не сложно исправить в ромбовых инструментах. Но это всё только догадки.

Comment: @alexolut https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140036/260198 не сложно